# Chrome 41: Force Reload when pressing the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, page-refresh

I'm trying something similar to this: [Force reload/refresh when pressing the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071838/force-reload-refresh-when-pressing-the-back-button)

Unfortunately, the suggested code doesn't work in Chrome 41:

```
window.onpageshow = function(evt) {
// If persisted then it is in the page cache, force a reload of the page.
if (evt.persisted) {
    document.body.style.display = "none";
    location.reload();
}};
```

Is there a newer solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953382/how-to-force-page-refresh-on-browser-back-click

Comment: This works :-) Could you post this as an answer so I can mark the question as done?

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953382/how-to-force-page-refresh-on-browser-back-click) that addresses the problem using localStorage/sessionStorage.