# how to reload page after delete form in node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is my first project with nodejs, and probably I am asking something trivial.
I hava a table to display list of items, that can be filtered in between two date.
The table has a link to edit and a form button to delete.

When I click to edit a line, I move to the editing page, I perform my actions and when I go back to the filtered page this is reloaded.
I follow answer 2 of this question, [how to force page refresh on browser back click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953382/how-to-force-page-refresh-on-browser-back-click)

My problem is that I cannot achieve the same result with the delete form. 
I tried res.redirect('back'); and res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
Can I be pointed to the right direction ?

Thanks Alb

```
app.search('/search', function(req, res) {
var sdate = req.body.sdate
var edate =  req.body.edate
var sdate_full = req.body.sdate+' 00:00:00'
var edate_full =  req.body.edate+' 24:59:59'
    console.log("post received: %s %s", sdate, edate);
    console.log("post received: %s %s", sdate_full, edate_full);
req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_INSERT_DATE >= ? AND item_INSERT_DATE <= ?", [sdate_full, edate_full], function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err)
            res.render('user/list', {
                moment: moment,
                title: 'Items',
                data: ''
            })
        } else {
            res.render('user/list', {
                moment: moment,
                title: 'Items',
                data: rows
            })
        }
    })
})

})

app.delete('/delete/(:id)', function(req, res, next) {
var user = { item_ID: req.params.id }
req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
    conn.query('DELETE FROM table WHERE item_ID = ' + req.params.id, user, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err)
            res.redirect('/')
        } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Item deleted ! id = ' + req.params.id)
            res.redirect(??????)
        }

    })
})
})
```

The form I start from is '/search', which filter my table list. The problem is that I can only redirect to '/' (which gives me the entire list), but not the search page updated with the line deleted. This is the last tiny bit to end this little job.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing you could do is, when you click in the delete button in the frontend, call

```js
const desiredTimeInMilliSeconds = 100;

setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = window.location;
}, desiredTimeInMilliSeconds)
```

Comment: Hi Mensur, I updated the question, because not luck.